# Forms Error - Resolver must resolve module reference to a valid module

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio, winforms

When attempting the enter into Design mode (after double-clicking the form) '***Resolver must resolve module reference to a valid module***'
error appears. If I ignore and continue, then the compile fails on the wholesome. There are no specific pointers what to correct except giant exception message.

[image]

Comment: Had same issue lots of times. There is an error in the designer.cs file. These are hard to find.  I usually have to comment code in the designer file until I isolate the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, what I did is I just by excluding (manually) Designer.cs file and re-including it
again, it all worked flawlessly. Obviously compiler can't handle obsolete chunks of data
so it resides until the manual re-inclusion.